# Can i use one .htpasswd file for different folders on Linux server

Tags: permissions, .htaccess, .htpasswd

I have many modules in my codeignitor application as

```
module/products
module/billing
module/cms
module/groups
.....
```

Some of the above modules are accessible to admin user only so I want to put .htpasswd file to restrict those module. In my module structure of the application, how can I add .htpasswd file to restrict only few modules and also I want to put only one .htpasswd file.

Answer (score 0):

The [`AuthUserFile`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authn_file.html#authuserfile) directive is used per directory in the config, or in an `.htaccess` file; there's no reason you can't specify the same file for multiple directories.